# Can Update Vuforia database data throgh AR app?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, vuforia-cloud-recognition

I hope to create AR app to simulation  graphs as marker-based way.I plan to do, show a graph model on marker and I need to change that simulation with user input parameters.so I needed to update Vuforia database.I need to update vuforia database data by replacing or updating new graph model instead of previous model on the same target. can I do it?